# Conflicto entre dos eventos simultáneos en Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Tengo un pequeño formulario con un campo de entrada. Creé una `<div>` con una "x" y la posicioné de forma relativa a la derecha del campo de entrada. La idea es que cuando el usuario clique en la "x" se limpie el texto ingresado previamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese evento "click" es controlado por medio de Knockout. El problema es que Knockout también controla un evento "blur" que va a observar el texto ingresado y realizar determinadas acciones según cuál sea el contenido.

Siempre que el usuario ingresa un texto y a continuación clica la "x", por algún motivo que no logro descubrir, Knockout procesa el evento "blur" y no el "click". Es como si ese evento tuviese precedencia sobre el otro.

Necesito alguna pista, gracias de antemano!

Dejo un fragmento de HTML para ilustrar (editado):

```
<form class="form" data-bind="submit: processSearch">

        <div class="form-group text-center search">
          <!-- Search -->
          <div class="input-container">
            <input type="search" class="form-control text-center"
              data-bind="textInput: search, event: { focus: focusSearch, blur: processSearch }, blurBubble: false">
            <div class="clear-container" data-bind="click: clearSearch, clickBubble: false">
              <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hola AleD, podrías colocar el código relevante a tu pregunta para ver donde está el error?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz, dejé un fragmento de HTML, espero que ayude.

Comment: No es precisamente que tengra precedencia, lo que pasa es que al hacer click en cualquier otro objeto lo primero que sucede es que el objeto que tenía el foco lo pierde (blur) para pasarselo al nuevo elemento. Ya que el boton gano el foco se lanza el evento click. 
En Knockout es nesesario que pase eso ya que es el trabajo de los observables, notificar al modelo cada cambio en el view

Comment: @Lato, y habría alguna forma de saltearme ese evento "blur" y así poder procesar el "click", o no es posible?

Comment: No se si se pueda hacer, pero tal vez te puedas dar alguna idea con la documentación [The "enable" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html) o [The "hasFocus" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html)